# Multiply *float32 and int value

Tags: go, floating-point

I have 2 fields that I have to multiply. One is a `*float32` field and another is an `int` field. How can I multiply these fields?

```
var totalPrice *float32
var price *float32
var volume int
```

this code doesn't work. I get the error ... `mismatched types *float32 ...`

`totalPrice = price * volume`

Comment: `*price * float32(volume)`

Comment: Why pointer to float32 ?

Comment: mkopriva, thx for the answer but I get the error message:
`cannot use *price * float32(volume) (type float32) as type *float32 in assignment`

Comment: mostafa, I can have a nullable price in my database

Comment: You never want to use floats for price data, especially float32 which has very limited precision.

Comment: @mrr. use the address operator on the result of that expression. (https://play.golang.com/p/mlH7y5ccC-D)

Comment: @JimB why you always put focus on what is wrong, instead of showing what would be the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to *convert* using type conversion as is [explained quickly here](https://tour.golang.org/basics/13). In this case as mkopriva highlight in his comment, you should convert `volume` variable's value to a float32.

Also allow to show a way to deal with nil values that has a meaning in the application level, for that i wrote the float32PtrToFloat(*float32,float32) with the second parameter that allows you to specify what value shall be taken instead of nil.

Assuming that a nil value translates to zero value, here goes the complete example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var totalPrice *float32
    var price *float32
    var volume int

    var total = float32PtrToFloat(price, 0) * float32(volume)
    totalPrice = &total
    fmt.Println(*totalPrice)

}

func float32PtrToFloat(price *float32, valueIfNil float32) float32 {
    if price == nil {
        return valueIfNil
    } else {
        return *price
    }
}
```

And a personal reading, following JimB advice, try to not use floats for currency values as floating point arithmetic is not reliable. Instead use integer values, using the 1 as the lower value in the current currency, for example:

- 1 = 1 penny (or)
- 1 = 1 cent (or)
- 1 = 1 centavo (in my case)